# Add objects to an existing field using yq

Tags: yaml, yq

I have the following yaml file:

```
some:
  fields: ...
# ...

images:
  image_1:
    name: "some-name"
    value: 1111
# ...

some:
  other-fields: ...
```

I would like to add generated objects in place with the same template as `image_1` has:

```
image_<no>:
  name: "<name>"
  value: <value>
```

I have found how to build an object using `yq` however, I have problem with adding it to the existing field (`images`), under last element. The simplified script I'm using to build an object.

```
yq eval '{"image_no": {"name": "my_name", value: 1111}' myfile.yml
```

Comment: mikefarah/yq does not yet support addition to maps i.e. to your `images` node

Comment: @Inian is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Using [yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) your task can be solved easily.

The bash script shows two slighty different versions:

1. In version 1 the three parameters `imageNo` `name` and `value` are passed to `yq`.
2. In version 2 the parameter `imageNo` is calculated within the script from the current number of images.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

FILE='
some:
  fields: "value"

images:
  image_1:
    name: "some-name"
    value: 1111
  image_2:
    name: "some-name-2"
    value: 1112
  image_3:
    name: "some-name-3"
    value: 1113

some:
  other-fields: "other-value"
'

echo adding new image to yaml - version 1
yq -y --argjson imageNo 4 --arg name "my_name" --argjson value 1114 '
  .images += { 
               "image_\($imageNo)":
               { 
                 name: $name,
                 value: $value
               }
             }' <<< "$FILE"

echo adding new image to yaml - version 2
yq -y --arg name "my_name" --argjson value 1114 '
  (.images | keys | length + 1) as $imageNo
  | .images += { 
                 "image_\($imageNo)":
                   { 
                     name: $name,
                     value: $value
                   }
               }' <<< "$FILE"
```

### `output` version 1 and version 2

```yaml
some:
  other-fields: other-value
images:
  image_1:
    name: some-name
    value: 1111
  image_2:
    name: some-name-2
    value: 1112
  image_3:
    name: some-name-3
    value: 1113
  image_4:
    name: my_name
    value: 1114
```